# How can I get current_page? to match multiple actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

My problem is that I'm trying to do something like

```
current_page?(controller: 'tigers', action:('index'||'new'||'edit'))
```

which returns true when the controller is tigers and the action is either index, new, or edit.

The above does not throw an error, but only matches the first action.

Help!

Comment: Personally I would just write a method to check these one by one and be done with it. Jumping through hoops to try to one-line this check is not worth the time.

Comment: Interesting. I'm still relatively noobish, trying to figure out the optimal way to do things. Appreciate the input.

Comment: ruby is great and the magic methods it sometimes gives can be intoxicating at times, but never forget that sometimes just writing the code is the best way to solve the problem. ;)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

More verbose, but works:

```
current_page?(controller:'bikes') &&
 (current_page?(action:'index') ||
  current_page?(action:'new')   ||
  current_page?(action:'edit'))
```

Less verbose, also works:

```
params[:controller] == 'bikes' && %w(index new edit).include?(params[:action])
```

%w() is a shortcut for building arrays of space delimited strings

Comment: All good answers, I chose this one because its a one-liner like I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: every page visit is always including controller and action in its params therefore you could do the oneline

Answer (score 6):

You can also do something like this:

```
if current_page?(root_path) || current_page?(about_path) || current_page?(contact_path) || current_page?(faq_path) || current_page?(privacy_path)
```

Note: Do not leave blank space before parenthesis otherwise it won't work.

Comment: **Using the route helper as seen above seems more flexible than other options listed.**

I was running into an issue where a template in my root project using the more explicit syntax (e.g. supplying action, controller in a hash) was causing issues in a mounted engine that was sharing the same template. Basically, the engine was expecting the specified controller to be a part of the engine. Using the route path helper remedied the situation! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using the current_page? method is to check the params hash directly:

```
params[:action] == ('index' || 'new' || 'edit')
```

Will return true if on index, new, or edit. You can also access the controller through params[:controller].

Comment: This didn't seem to be working for me, but I may have been putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: It won't work. ('index' || 'new' || 'edit') basically equals 'index', because it's truthy.

Comment: You could instead do:  `[:index, :new, :edit].include? params[:action]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all actions related to a specific controller you can use 'controller_name' method like this

```rb
if controller_name == 'your_controller_name'
```

'controller_name' is a method inherited from the ActionController::Base class, it's available in all views and helpers by default.