# Rails 6 : Active link helper for all pages served by a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to add a class to a link's container when the link is active.

To be more precise : I want a class applied on a sidebar link container if the user is navigating through a group of pages, usually related to a model. For example, for the user management part of the site, I want the sidebar link to look active on the user index, the user creation form and the user show page.

I have this helper method :

```
def active_class_if_url(urls)
  urls.include?(request.path) ? 'sidebar-active-item' : ''
end
```

And I use it in my views like so :

```
<div class="<%= active_class_if_url([users_path, new_user_path]) %>">
```

It works for index pages and creation forms, but I can't make it work when the path helper has a parameter, for example a show page like user_path(@user).

How can I make my helper understand these paths ? Is that even the right method to do this ?

Update 1

I tried the current_page method, as suggested by @markets, still not working. Tried this :

```
def active_class_if_controller(controller)
  current_page?(controller: controller) ? 'sidebar-active-item' : ''
end
```

hoping this would do the trick :

```
<div class="<%= active_class_if_controller('users') %>">
```

But nothing changed, it gets only the index action. I'm currently trying something along this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21536442/3219759

Update 2

Solved via the previous answer :

```
def active_class_if_controller(controller)
  params[:controller] == controller ? 'sidebar-active-item' : ''
end
```

Does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the provided helper by Rails `current_page?` (docs: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-current_page-3F). You can even check for specific params if you need it.

**Examples:**

If you in the page: `http://www.example.com/shop/checkout?order=desc&page=1`

```rb
current_page?(action: 'process')
# => false

current_page?(action: 'checkout')
# => true

current_page?(controller: 'library', action: 'checkout')
# => false

current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout')
# => true

current_page?(controller: 'shop', action: 'checkout', order: 'desc', page: '2')
# => false

current_page?('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout')
# => true

current_page?('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout', check_parameters: true)
# => false

current_page?('/shop/checkout')
# => true

current_page?('http://www.example.com/shop/checkout?order=desc&page=1')
# => true
```

---

Alternatively, you can also write your own simple helper, using the `controller_name` (and/or `action_name`) macro:

```rb
def active_class_if_controller(controller)
  'sidebar-active-item' if controller_name == controller
end
```

Comment: Solved it in a different way, updated the question.

Comment: Ok @Ruff9! I just added another potential solution, using the `controller_name` macro.

Comment: it's even shorter than mine !